# RestTemplate Jackson Parsing - Invalid mime type "{application/json, q=1000}": Invalid token character '{' in token "{

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson, resttemplate

I am invoking a multipart request using Resttemplate, in one of our environment, we are getting an exception:

```
 Invalid mime type "{application/json, q=1000}": Invalid token character '{' in token "{
```

On some debugging, we found it is due to Jackson parsing, we followed some of these recommendations,
Added content negotiation headers:

```
baseHeader.add(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
    baseHeader.add(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_CHARSET, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()

);
```

And modified Resttemplate Configs:

```
    @Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {

    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters = new ArrayList<>();
    StringHttpMessageConverter stringConverter = new StringHttpMessageConverter();
    stringConverter.setWriteAcceptCharset(false);
    converters.add(stringConverter);
    restTemplate.setMessageConverters(converters);

    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    return new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
}
```

But both didn't worked, we updated Spring version to 2.1.6, still, the issue exists.

Comment: Looks like your requests are malformed. Neither the `q=1000` nor the brackets are part of any mime type, hence your request can't be parsed. The error should lie on the client side, it is not a Jackson Problem.

Comment: To verify @TA 's hypothesis, record the full HTTP response (header and body) and add it to your question.

Comment: Yes, the response contains the MimeType as "{application/json, q=1000}". Is there ay Jackson config where we can add this Custom mime type or avoid parsing this response

Comment: @JagadheeswaranMohan You could add your case as a custom mime type to your function but I would advise against it. Your `q=1000` should logically have nothing to do with the mime type and should therefore probably be handled as a request parameter or similar.

Comment: The q=1000 is coming as part of the server response, and we limited to do modifications on that, can we handle in our spring application?